# Make an <img> tag extend past the <body> tag in css

Tags: html, css, image, header, center

I'm trying to develop a header area which expands past the usual 960px wide container, without using a background image, my reason for this is because an `<img>` tag would work better in my case.

My problem is, if i place my image in the container, such as this code example:

```
<style>
   #container {
       width: 960px;
       margin: 0 auto;
   }
</style>
<div id="container">
  <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="my image" />
</div>
```

I want to be able to take this image an center it, across the page, expanding past its container to the end of the viewport, without scrollbars being added, assume the size of the image remains at a constant 1280px wide, but the height varies.

I've been trying this morning, but i don't think it can be done without setting overflow:hidden on the body tag, which is bad because i'd like it t obe able to scroll if the window is smaller than the container.

I hope you guys can help :)

Comment: What's the reasoning for using `<img />` instead of a background image?

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. The reason was to try out an alternative method of doing the same task.

My old solution was to use a wrapper, with the background image applied, and then setting a min width of 960, so that upon resize, the background image stops trying to be at the center at a point (if that makes sense).

My idea with the <img> tag was to replicate this, originally i was just hoping it'd be a case of negative margins but i forgot about the overflow aspect :\ 

After toying around for a while, i thought i might post on here to see if anyone else has tried to do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, it does not work. Why does it has to be inside the container?

You could do it like this.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>  
html, body{ 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
} 
#header{
width: 2000px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#container{
width: 960px;
height: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
#page{
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
}
</style>  
 </head>
<body>
    <div id="page"> 
    <div id="header"> 
      <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="my image" />  
    </div> 
<div id="container">  
</div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks lukas for your second attempt :) This would work i recon, however i'd like to stick away from creating two containers, so i recon i shall stick with my original background image approach :) Thank you ever so much for your support however! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

If the img is to be placed exactly at x-pos:0 and Y-pos:0, you could use position:absolute to placed it:

```
img#my_header{

 position:absolute; // Tell the browser to break document work flow for this ID

 z-index:1; // Tell the browser to pull up in the stack this ID by 1

 top:0; // tell the browser to place this ID at 0px from top of view port

 left:0; // tell the browser to place this ID at 0px from left of view port

}
```

This is a sample, to give you an idea who you can break the document workflow to set your img tag into the desired place... adjusting top and left coordinates, you should solve it!

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried this but had no luck, it positioned it great, however scroll bars still appear on a large image (say 1280px)

I think i can see now why we use background images instead of img tags for this kinda thing

Answer (score 1):

My thought is similar to Lucas's. Take the  out of the container, and put it in it's own container (id="header" for example). Set #header to width: 100% (which should be the width of the viewport, and overflow: hidden. Then position #header as you want - use Zuul's suggestion of absolute positioning if necessary.

```
...
<style type="text/css">
#header { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0; }
</style>
...
<div id="header">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="My Image" />
</div>
...
```

I think that should work out for you.